# Can I specify a maximum precision width for numbers with sprintf in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use Perl's `sprintf` function to specify a maximum precision width for floating point number? After reading the documentation, I believe it's not, but may be I have overlooked something.

So, if I have have 4.12, I'd like to have the number formated as `4.12`.

```
my $abc = 4.12;
my $out = sprintf("%?...", $abc); # $out eq '4.12';
```

Yet, if the number has more than 6 digits of precision, I want only 6 digits:

```
my $def = 1.23456789;
my $out = sprintf("%?...", $def); # $out eq '1.234568';
```

Is this possible with `sprintf`?

**Edit**

Currentyl, I am using

```
sub output_number {
  my $number = shift;

  my $ret = sprintf("%.6f", $number);

  $ret =~ s/0*$//g;
  $ret =~ s/\.$//g;

  return $ret;
}
```

for my purposes, which does what I need. But I hoped there is a more elegant way. Preferably a one liner, not necessarily restricted to the use of `sprintf`.

Note also, that the suggested `printf ("%.7g", $number)` doesn't behave the way I want (for example for `$n = 0.00000000001;`.

Comment: `man sprintf` could be a nice read...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use `%.<n>g`:

```
perl -e 'printf "%.7g", 4.12'          =>   4.12
perl -e 'printf "%.7g", 4.12345678'    =>   4.123457
```

But if exponential notation really ruins your day, and your installed perl is modern enough, there's always

```
sprintf("%.6f",$number) =~ s/\.?0+$//r
```

Comment: Note that large or small numbers (either sign) will come out as `1.1234567e+123`

Comment: Indeed. `perl -e "printf('%.7g', 0.000000001);"` results in `1e-009` and I'd like this to be a `0`. `perl -e "printf('%.7g', 10_000_000);"` results in `1e+007` and I'd like a `10000000`.